# Twilio Auth API is not working my in local system

Tags: ajax, twilio

I had integrated Twilio Auth API in my React project i getting

```
fetch('https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(resObject),
  dataType : 'json',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-Authy-API-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  },
})
```

I am getting this error

```
Fetch API cannot load https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

I Now this is a cross-origin issue but I am not able to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authy developer evangelist here.

It is a very bad idea to include your Authy API key in the client side of your application. A malicious user could take your API key and use it to abuse your users via the [Authy API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy/authy-totp).

We recommend that you perform your API requests on the server side, so that no-one can get at your API key. If you are using Node.js as a server, there is an [Authy Node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/authy#start-phone-verification) to make this nice and easy. There are libraries available for other languages too.